# BX slider auto and click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have made this slider with **auto slide show**. I also need **manual controls** working well on it, even if used with regressively slide switching. Problem comes when I click on labels for navigation very fast and randomly, it gets stuck at some point and doesn't switch to clicked slide instead it moves to its next slide. Please refer this **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/zbrcww6a/10/.

I also tried **stopping auto** and then replaying it on click event of labels:

```
$(document).on('click','.bx-pager-link',function() {
    slider.stopAuto(); // stops auto on click of pager
    slider.startAuto(); // starts auto on click of pager
});
```

But it doesn't make any difference.